# Add required field to file upload

Tags: visual-workflow, fileupload

I created two custom fields at the files object which are required. How can I add this fields to a flow with the file upload component?
I know how can I add fields to the Screen Flow, but the Upload start immediiately if I select a file and i have no Chance to add the field Infos.

Answer (score 0):

There is a attribute on file upload in screen flow called **Disabled**.
If set to $GlobalConstant.True, the component is disabled. This attribute accepts single-value Boolean resources.

You can set the value of it true and false based on the values in required field in screen flow. It will make sure user can only upload file when they have selected the required fields.

or you can put the required fields on different screen than file upload. This will make sure they will only see upload file option when they have entered the required field.

Comment: Ok, but how can I put the required fields content to the new files record? If the user select at Screen 1 the required fields and in screen 2 the User Upload the file, how can I assign the fieldcontent to the record? I can Store the value in a resource, but of the User close the second Screen without finish the Flow, the resources will be lost.

Comment: Any ideas for may Problem?